# Error in constructed URL for getJSON method

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following jQuery call in the razor view.

```
$.getJSON('/Controller/ActionName/'+ @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Name"] + '?Date=' + ('#StartDate').val(), function (data) {
    alert(data);
    });
```

The error in chrome browser console is that the below URL has returned no page found.

```
http://localhost:{portNumber}/Controller/ActionName/John?Date=9/21/2014&_=1413867422739
```

it is true because of the added extra token to the end of the url. 
Can any one please let me know the reasons for the extra token?
I have an appropriate method in the controller and not able to figure out a solution. 
The routeConfig.cs file is not changed and it has the default values to it. 
Please let me know in comments if you need further information. I am not able to understand which information to furnish.

Route information:

```
{
    routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", name = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
}
```

Action Signature in the controller

```
public JsonResult ActionName(string**?** name, DateTime startDate)
        {
            var model = new ViewModel();
            model.loadItems(name**.value**, startDate);
            return Json(model.Data,  **JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet**);
        }
```

Answer:
Made the above changes in surrounded by ** and the code worked.
Thank you for the comments and answers.
Update:
I have mentioned the default values in order to hide the unrequired information.
localhost is correct and other pages are working fine just a small part of ui which is related to this ajax call is not working.
No controller is name something else.

Can you please provide a solution for sending date values in URLS?

Comment: Whats the signature of the method your calling?

Comment: The extra token is to prevent the ajax call from being cached, it is a random number that will be appended to each request. It shouldn't affect anything, but get the Action signature from you controller will help.

Comment: What's `loclhst000000`?

Comment: Your problem is the date format. "9/21/2014"
You can't have "/" in the get variables

Comment: Is your controller really named ControllerController?

Comment: I think the problem is with url itself. Is it possible to send `Jhon` using this format `http://localh0st:{portNumber}/Controller/ActionName/John?Date=9/21/2014&_=1413867422739`

Answer (score 1):

Change you call to (assuming your controller is really named ControllerController

```
$.getJSON('/Controller/ActionName/', { name: @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Name"], startDate: $('#StartDate').val(), function (data) {..
```

You have a few problems here. Your default route accepts a parameter named ID but your method only has parameters `name` and `startDate`. You are not passing any parameters with those names (you are passing one for `date` but that does not match the method signature parameter)

Note you should not hard code the controller and action names this way. The recommend ways is

```
var url = '@Url.Action("ActionName", "Controller")';
```

Comment: Yes, I have forgot to update the route information here in the question. will try your suggestion. Thanks for the inputs.

Comment: or change you method to be public JsonResult ActionName(string ? Id, DateTime startDate).

Answer (score 0):

```
 var StartDate= ('#StartDate').val();    
 var url="/Controller/ActionName/'+ @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Name"] + '/";

     $.ajax({
     url: url,
     data: { Date: StartDate},
     cache: false,
     type: "POST",
    success: function (data){
         },
    error: function (data){
         }
    });
```